# How to reference type and make sure import is not stripped by typescript compiler

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

I'm writing a ts transformer that finds named class decorator then replace decorator's call and passes a map with names and types of all props of decorated class, e.g.:

source file:

```
import BigNumber from "bignumber.js";

@decorator()
class AClass {
   aProp: BigNumber;
}
```

output:

```
import BigNumber from "bignumber.js";

@decorator({"aProp": BigNumber})
class AClass {
   aProp: BigNumber;
}
```

I'm getting prop name and type from PropertyDeclaration:

```
const clazzProps = [];
for (const childNode of clazz.members) {
    if (ts.isPropertyDeclaration(childNode)) {
       const type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(childNode);
       if (type.isClass()) {
           clazzProps.push(ts.createPropertyAssignment(
              ts.createIdentifier(childNode.name.getText()),
              childNode.type.typeName
           );
       }
    }
}
```

So far so good, however after compilation import statement is removed from output js file, cause in the source file BigNumber was only referenced as a type, not as a value. **My question is, how to properly check if BigNumber is not a type only and make sure that import will not be stripped ?**

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but still.

> Typescript compiler has four main phases—parsing, binding, type checking, and emitting. Binding is where the relationships between identifiers are resolved, but transformation happens during the "emitting" phase.

That means on a moment when transform happened typescript already know that `BigNumber` is used only as type in this context and following it's own rules all imports which point only to type is not emitted to js.

Unfortunately, there is no simple solution and you probably will be needed to add this imports by yourself during the transform.

The same use-case and problem was solved here https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/blob/master/lib/plugin/visitors/model-class.visitor.ts

It's resolving types of property using type checker and finding the file this type pointint to and store this paths in `importsToAddPerFile`, than in `updateImports` the are added to the source file.

I'm generally not recommending using a TypeChecker (it's slower, might not be available in some context and can produce weird results if you have few transform relying on it) in transforms and probably for simple cases you can just read what imports you already have and re-create them manually.